# Custom View not drawing itself

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I read different questions here about this topic, but I still can't find an answer. Feel free to close this question for any reason.

I have a simple `Circle` class that extends `View`.

The code for this class is:

```
public class ProgressCircle extends View {
    Paint mCirclePaint;
    float extRadius;
    float viewWidth, viewHeight;
    float centerX, centerY;

    public ProgressCircle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        init();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        float xpad = (float) getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
        float ypad = (float) getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();
        float ww = (float)w - xpad; float hh = (float)h - ypad;
        extRadius = Math.min(ww, hh) / 2;

        viewWidth = this.getWidth();
        viewHeight = this.getHeight();
        centerX = viewWidth / 2; centerY = viewHeight / 2;

        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, extRadius, mCirclePaint);
        canvas.drawText("ciao", 0, 0, mCirclePaint);    
    }

    private void init() {
        mCirclePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mCirclePaint.setColor(0x666666);
        mCirclePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    }
```

I confirmed that every method in this classed is called when the main activity is created (through the use of some `Log.d()`s). I added a `<com.mypackage.Circle>` element in my main activity's `LinearLayout` and after that I added a sample testing button.

What I achieved is that the button is shown while my `Circle` isn't, but still the button (which in the `LinearLayout` comes after the `Circle`) is not the first element of the layout: that makes me think that something actually happens, but nothing gets drawn.

Comment: try removing `super.onDraw(canvas);`

Comment: @aragaer Nothing changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was just a silly problem: the color in `mCirclePaint.setColor(0x666666)` was an invalid one. It worked with `mCirclePaint.setColor(Color.RED)` or with any other color defined in the `res` folder.

If you need to specify a color value, you'll have to include the transparency byte (otherwise it is not a 32bit integer that you are specifying, but a 24bit). So 0x666666 is invalid, but 0xff666666 is a valid color and will draw.

Comment: Nice catch, this fixed it for me. I had `0x00000000` instead of `0xff000000` :P

Answer (score 0):

After reading the documentation(http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html):

> The Android framework will only call onDraw() as necessary. Each time
>   that your application is prepared to be drawn, you must request your
>   View be invalidated by calling invalidate(). This indicates that you'd
>   like your View to be drawn and Android will then call your onDraw()
>   method (though is not guaranteed that the callback will be
>   instantaneous).

Also another thing worth checking is the dimensions you're drawing insure nothing is invalid like a height of 0 etc..

Comment: Added various combinations of `invalidate()`, nothing changed.

Comment: then the only explanation is that your parameters that are being drawn are invalid

Answer (score 0):

I notice you're not overriding [View.onMeasure()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure%28int,%20int%29).

Because you're not overriding this method `onsizeChanged()` might be passed size 0. You can check this by putting a breakpoint in the `onSizechanged()` method or printing to Logcat.

Comment: it calls `onSizeChanged()` with non-zero arguments.

Comment: If you're getting a positive non-zero size passed in first I assume it's giving you a size that can be seen i.e. not 1 pixel by 1 pixel. You could always then check where the View is going to be drawn on sceen by calling getLeft() and getTop() and see if the return values are as expected.